# Can I safely temporarily remove the exhaust and intake of my furnace?

Tags: hvac

It's the cooling season where I live, so we are not using the furnace at all - air conditioning only.

Can I safely remove the exhaust and intake pipes in the picture below, in order to rebuild the wall behind the furnace (which the pipes go through)?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring possible legalities, yes, but do be sure to take steps to avoid the remotest possibility of accidental activation/ignition. Shut off gas valve, etc.

Depending on applicable local rules & regulations, (and possibly the terms of your insurance) you might need to get the reassembled piping blessed by a certified or licensed gas technician before placing the unit back in operation, or you might not.

Comment: That’s fair enough - I’ll definitely have it inspected before using it again.

Comment: Was there 2-for-1 on pipe angle sections the day the fitter put that lot together??

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru That looks to my amateur eye like that's original piping being adapted to a newer unit.